# IS Curve and AD Relation

Tags: macroeconomics

Relation between Aggregate demand and Investment saving
What happens to the Investment saving curve when Aggregate demand curve is steeply sloped?
I know that with a higher Marginal propensity to consume, AD has a steeper slope.